# How to get amount of Retrofit Queues?

Tags: android, queue, retrofit

I want to know the number of queues from the retrofit, which I want to use if queue = 0 then it will proceed to the next process, I have problems if I don't check before making the next transaction where the value of the previous transaction is saved in the next transaction, I have done search on google but don't get the right results